# ¿Como cambio el color de fondo de un dialogFragment?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy llamando un calendario de la libreria MonthYearPicker para solo mostrar mes y año.

```
 MonthYearPickerDialogFragment dialogFragment = MonthYearPickerDialogFragment.getInstance(month,year);
                dialogFragment.setOnDateSetListener(new MonthYearPickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {}
```

El problema es que cuando se abre el calendario el fondo es de color gris y no eh podido cambiarlo.
El tema que usa mi actividad es:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlue</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlue</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Eh probado usando:                `dialogFragment.setStyle(MonthYearPickerDialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,R.style.NoActionBar);`
El problema es que desconozco con atributo se cambia el fondo.
Nota: el color de los botones son los únicos que eh podido cambiar.

[image: Asi se ve al abrir el calendario]